# Cannot copy Qwidgets in tab to a new tab

Tags: c++, qt4, qt-creator

Ok so I have been going insane trying to find an answer to this for a day now. What I am trying to do is make a copy of all the widgets in a tab. I want to transfer the copy to a new tab. Think of a form in a tab, and when you click "New Tab" it displays the same form but blank. I am new to QTCreator so any pointers would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to clarify. Are you talking about copying the widgets to a new tab at design-time or run-time?

Comment: runtime. Sorry about my clarity. I just want to create a form to go into a tab that can be copied into x number of tabs.

Answer (score 2):

Any class that derives from `QObject` is [not copyable](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor-or-assignment-operator). If you want to "copy" a widget, then perhaps a model-view architecture would be a better fit where you have two different views representing the model.

Another thought: you could have each class that needs to be copyable create a state object that could then be used to set the state on the copy.

Since you're just trying to display the same form in multiple places, you could do something like this.

First, create your form which I'll assume is called `MyForm`:

```
class MyForm: QWidget {...};
```

Then, in the parent form:

```
void ContainerForm::ContainerForm(...) {
    connect(pbAddNewTab, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(addNewTab()));
}

void ContainerForm::addNewTab() {
    tabWidget->addTab(new MyForm(this));
}
```

You may need to pull out the `new` so you can setup signals and slots, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the new form is blank then it is not a copy. All you need to do is create a new instance of your form widget.